# Get the content of siblings elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation, siblings

I need to get the content of some specific elements using jquery, the problem is that i have the same element repeating on my page:

```
<div class="content">
   <img alt="" src="">
   <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
   <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
   <ul>
     <li><a class="uiButton">Test</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

So, the div.content repeat on my page many times and I want to get only the contents of the div that holds the button was clicked. I've added a onclick event on the .uiButton and tried to use parent(".txt") or siblings(".txt"), but dont seems to work...

```
$(".uiButton").click(function(){ 
  var txt = $(this).parent(".txt").text(); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.txt` isn't a parent, and even then it has to be a *direct* parent ([`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) matches the immediate parent *if* it matches the selector), instead you need:

```
$(".uiButton").click(function(){ 
  var txt = $(this).closest("ul").siblings(".txt").text(); 
});
```

The alternative is to go all the way up to `.content` (via [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)) to be safe then traverse down with [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(".uiButton").click(function(){ 
  var txt = $(this).closest(".content").find(".txt").text(); 
});
```

Comment: The reason I picked your second method, was that the `ul` was unnamed, I prefer to pick named components in case of structural change. +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to go up to the wrapper and down, you can go to siblings, but in this case it will be harder.

```
$(".uiButton").click(function(){ 
  var txt = $(this).closest('.content').find('.txt').text(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('p.txt');
```

Might work.